# How can I using put method to update data on the vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

My ajax axios like this :

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', user.avatar)
formData.append('selected_data', JSON.stringify(user))
axios.post('/member/profile/update', 
    formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
)
.then(response => cb(response))
.catch(error => ecb(error))
```

My routes like this :

```
Route::post('update', 'member\UserController@update')->name('member.profile.update');
```

If the script executed, it works. I success get the data sended

But here, I want to change post method to put method. Because this used to update profile

I change like this :

```
axios.put(...
```

And the routes :

```
Route::put('update', ...
```

I don't success get the data sended. The data sended is empty

How can I solve this problem?

**Update** :

If I `console.log(user)`, the result like this :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel uses method spoofing for PUT, use `axios.post` and add the following to your requests data:

```
data: {
    ...
    _method: 'PUT',
    ...
}
```

You can do:

```
formData.append('_method', 'PUT')
```

Complete example using axios:

```
axios.post('/user', { _method: 'PUT', foo: 'bar' })
  .then(function (response) { console.log(response); })
  .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); });
```

[Form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: Where I define `_method: 'PUT'`? I using ajax to send data. Try to update your answer completely

Comment: Add it to your formData variable

Comment: Okay. And the routes stay like this : `Route::put('update', ...`?

Comment: Yes that should work fine. `POST` will also work since it's not a true `PUT` anyways.

Comment: Actually the post also works well. But I replace it with put because this form is used for update data

Comment: Right, it's the idea of form method spoofing that is important here.

Comment: Yeah. I want to ask again. I have another ajax that does not use formData variable. Actually I use formData variable to upload image. How do I define `_method: 'PUT'` if my ajax does not use formData variable?

Comment: My another ajax like this : `axios.post('/member/profile/change-password', password)
.then(response => cb(response))
.catch(error => ecb(error))`. It does not using formData variable

Comment: I added an axios example to the answer